# String should not contain two consecutive forward slashes and does not end with a forward slash '/'

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I have a Regex to allow alphanumeric characters and does not allow special characters anywhere:

**^[a-zA-Z0-9,.:\s\'\+()?][a-zA-Z0-9,-./:\s\'\+()?]*$**

Now, I also need to restrict forward slash '/' at the last character of the string and the string should not contain two or more consecutive forward slashes anywhere.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this :

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9,-./:\s\'\+()?]*$)(?<!.*?\/{2,}.*$)(?<!.*\/$)
```

Explain:

- `(^[a-zA-Z0-9,-./:\s\'\+()?]*$)` -- string consist of as per your
  requirement..
- `(?<!.*?\/{2,}.*$)` -- there will not occure 2 or more times /
- `(?<!.*\/$)` -- string can not end with /

Comment: You can also restict (?<!^/.*)